# postgresql: reading binary blobs from php

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, blob

When i've try to read blob data from database, i've something like this:

```
xffd8ffe000104a46494600010201006000600000...
```

It's only on windows OS, on linux it works as it should be

sql:

```
select lob from table where id = ...
```

tried to use `::bytea`, nothing changed

in php just fetch with PDO and `file_put_contents`

I can convert data using `convert_from(lob, 'UTF8')` and it works with xml, but i need a solution for binary data (such as zip)

upd:
php code

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:...');
$pds = $db->prepare("select lob from table where id = :id");
$pds->bindParam('id', $id);
$pds->execute();
$r = $pds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
file_put_contents('Chrysanthemum.jpg', $r['lob']);
```

Comment: `file_put_contents`? Please show your code.

Comment: i've updated topic with php code

Comment: Have you tried explicitly binding the result column as LOB, as shown in http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php?

Comment: just tried, same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hex string shown in the question is generated by PostgreSQL 9.0 or higher when the `bytea_output` parameter is set to `hex`.

A plausible reason for the problem is that your PHP on Windows is linked with a pre-9.0 `libpq`. These older versions won't decode these contents.

Either you can upgrade to a newer `libpq`, or as a workaround you could do before selecting any bytea value:

```
$db->query("SET bytea_output=escape");
```

That will revert (for the current session) the bytea text representation to the old way that both older and newer versions of `libpq` can decode.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I was trying to figure this for a couple of days now..